# Using For Loop and Sum the Value with Case PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sum, key

I'm not getting this right when trying to sum values based on the case.
I thought it's gonna be an easy task, but it ain't the case so, please...

I have an array just like these:

```
[0] => Array (
    [NO_URUT] => 1
    [URAIAN] => BIAYA LANGSUNG
    [ACCOUNT] => -
    [LEVEL_NUM] => 1
    [GET_D1_PENYIMPANGAN_SD_INI] => 3
    )
[1] => Array (
    [NO_URUT] => 2
    [URAIAN] => BIAYA LANGSUNG
    [ACCOUNT] => -
    [LEVEL_NUM] => 2
    [GET_D1_PENYIMPANGAN_SD_INI] => 4
    )
[2] => Array (
    [NO_URUT] => 3
    [URAIAN] => BIAYA LANGSUNG
    [ACCOUNT] => -
    [LEVEL_NUM] => 3
    [GET_D1_PENYIMPANGAN_SD_INI] => 7
    )
[3] => Array (
    [NO_URUT] => 4
    [URAIAN] => BIAYA LANGSUNG
    [ACCOUNT] => -
    [LEVEL_NUM] => 1
    [GET_D1_PENYIMPANGAN_SD_INI] => 0
    )
[4] => Array (
    [NO_URUT] => 5
    [URAIAN] => BIAYA LANGSUNG
    [ACCOUNT] => -
    [LEVEL_NUM] => 2
    [GET_D1_PENYIMPANGAN_SD_INI] => 5
    )
[5] => Array (
    [NO_URUT] => 6
    [URAIAN] => BIAYA LANGSUNG
    [ACCOUNT] => -
    [LEVEL_NUM] => 3
    [GET_D1_PENYIMPANGAN_SD_INI] => 5
    )
```

What I want to do is sum the value of the array `GET_D1_PENYIMPANGAN_SD_INI` if the `LEVEL_NUM` from 3 meet the next `LEVEL_NUM` 1 And write the sum of the value between that.

I'm expecting the following result:

```
[0] => Array (
    [NO_URUT] => 1
    [URAIAN] => BIAYA LANGSUNG
    [ACCOUNT] => -
    [LEVEL_NUM] => 1
    [GET_D1_PENYIMPANGAN_SD_INI] => 3
    )
[1] => Array (
    [NO_URUT] => 2
    [URAIAN] => BIAYA LANGSUNG
    [ACCOUNT] => -
    [LEVEL_NUM] => 2
    [GET_D1_PENYIMPANGAN_SD_INI] => 4
    )
[2] => Array (
    [NO_URUT] => 3
    [URAIAN] => BIAYA LANGSUNG
    [ACCOUNT] => -
    [LEVEL_NUM] => 3
    [GET_D1_PENYIMPANGAN_SD_INI] => 7
    )
[3] => Array (
    [NO_URUT] => 4
    [URAIAN] => 
    [ACCOUNT] => 
    [LEVEL_NUM] => 
    [GET_D1_PENYIMPANGAN_SD_INI] => 14
    )
[4] => Array (
    [NO_URUT] => 5
    [URAIAN] => BIAYA LANGSUNG
    [ACCOUNT] => -
    [LEVEL_NUM] => 1
    [GET_D1_PENYIMPANGAN_SD_INI] => 0
    )
[5] => Array (
    [NO_URUT] => 6
    [URAIAN] => BIAYA LANGSUNG
    [ACCOUNT] => -
    [LEVEL_NUM] => 2
    [GET_D1_PENYIMPANGAN_SD_INI] => 5
    )
[6] => Array (
    [NO_URUT] => 7
    [URAIAN] => BIAYA LANGSUNG
    [ACCOUNT] => -
    [LEVEL_NUM] => 3
    [GET_D1_PENYIMPANGAN_SD_INI] => 5
    )
[7] => Array (
    [NO_URUT] => 8
    [URAIAN] => 
    [ACCOUNT] => 
    [LEVEL_NUM] => 
    [GET_D1_PENYIMPANGAN_SD_INI] => 10
    )
```

I've tried several ways with comparing the current value of Level_Num but it didn't work. I'm very confused about that.
Is there anyone who can help me to solve this? Thanks

What I've tried:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($rst);$i++){
   if ($i>1) {
      if ($rst[$i]->fields["LEVEL_NUM"]==3 && $rst[$i+1]->fields["LEVEL_NUM"]==1) {
         //Confuse...
      }
   }
}
```